# center an image vertically using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, center

In order to vertically center images (thumbnails on [this page](http://www.lolaartgallery.com/manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=39)) I tried this:

```
//Center the images (thumbnails) in the slideimg.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.work-view img').load(function(){
        //get img dimensions
        var h = $(this).height();
//alert(h);
        //set img position
        $(this).css('position','absolute');
        $(this).css('top','50%');
        $(this).css('margin-top',-Math.round(h/2) + 'px');
    });
});
```

but it works with Chrome but it doesn't work with firefox because firefox has the images in cache and .load is only for loading images.
So I am trying this:

```
//Center the images (thumbnails) in the slideimg.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function imageLoaded() { // function to invoke for loaded image
    //get img dimensions
    var h = $(this).height();
//alert(h);
    //set img position
    $(this).css('position','absolute');
    $(this).css('top','50%');
    $(this).css('margin-top',-Math.round(h/2) + 'px');
    }
    $('.work-view img').each(function(){
    if( this.complete ) {
        imageLoaded.call( this );
    } else {
        $(this).one('load', imageLoaded);
    }
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work...`$(this).css('position','absolute');` shifts them to the right instead of leaving them where they are horizontally...did I do something wrong?

Comment: no they should be also centered horizontally into the immediate html parent...but it is weird they go to right too much.   `$(this).css('position','absolute');` shifts them to the right...

Comment: Can you not add a load handler to the window rather than individual images? This ought to fix your cache not firing the load event problem.

Comment: @MattBurland you mean a window.load, isn't there a drawback?

Comment: @louis: thinking about it, there is one drawback, which is that it won't fire until *all* the images have loaded, which isn't a problem when they are cached, but is when they are not! Perhaps you could combine both approaches?

Comment: you're right, thanks. Actually the relative instead of absolute solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you are losing the target of your image.

```
//Center the images (thumbnails) in the slideimg.js
function imageLoaded(thisImage) { // function to invoke for loaded image
  //get img dimensions
  var h = $(thisImage).height();
  //set img position
  $(thisImage).css('position','absolute');
  $(thisImage).css('top','50%');
  $(thisImage).css('margin-top',-Math.round(h/2) + 'px');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.work-view img').each(function(){
  if( this.complete ) {
    imageLoaded.call( this );
  } else {
    var self = this;
    $(this).one('load', function(){ imageLoaded(self); });
  }
 });
});
```

What I did was to factor out the function, and added an argument to it because you are trying to pass `this` into the function multiple times but the function did not accept an argument. In the function, `this` as it was written was referring to the `window`.

Comment: actually I changed `$(this).css('position','absolute');` to `$(this).css('position','relative');` and it is ok now.  
I am not sure why though...